# Uninstall stuck Application

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, control-panel

I am an application developer.  I have been working on an installer for my application.   I seam to have messed it, my application is now stuck in control panel I cant uninstall it due to a loop in the install detection variables.

I know I have face this before years ago. However I can't seam to remember, was there a command for PowerShell or a registry change that can be done to remove stuck applications?

I haven't been able to find the solution in Google.

I checked

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName
```

Its not listed there looks like that's just Microsoft stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Uninstaller records](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) reside under Registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

If you know GUID of your application, you can navigate directly to proper subkey instead of searching through all the subkeys.

Delete the entire subkey. Before that, you might also want to delete files/folders referred in various values of your subkey, e.g. in `UninstallString` or `ModifyPath`.

---

Also, if your problematic uninstaller is an EXE file, you can build fixed version and replace current one at location shown in value `UninstallString`.
Then re-launch uninstallation and it should pass.

Comment: I think its setting the Guid everytime i build so this is going to take a while.  I assume i just need to delete that key?  Its just an MSI i was testing and mucked up seriously.

Comment: Actually i was able to search on the name of my application.  You are my hero thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well... there is solution for regular user- i use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) app (its free anyway). Can be used for very useful stuff. One of them is for uninstall programs (like this situation: check Tools -> Uninstall) and clear all wrong registry keys from Windows. In some situations - this can speed up your Windows boot process.

Good luck :)